# Deep learning: how can I save the computed model for prediction and how to load it later

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano

I am studying the main concepts of deep learning using the theano library. I am trying to run this code that appears in the tutorial. This piece of code runs for hours. How should I save the computed model for later use and how exactly I should load it back?

```
import cPickle
import gzip
import os
import sys
import time

import numpy

import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.signal import downsample
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv

from logistic_sgd import LogisticRegression, load_data
from mlp import HiddenLayer


class LeNetConvPoolLayer(object):
    """Pool Layer of a convolutional network """

    def __init__(self, rng, input, filter_shape, image_shape, poolsize=(2, 2)):
        """
        Allocate a LeNetConvPoolLayer with shared variable internal parameters.
        :type rng: numpy.random.RandomState
        :param rng: a random number generator used to initialize weights
        :type input: theano.tensor.dtensor4
        :param input: symbolic image tensor, of shape image_shape
        :type filter_shape: tuple or list of length 4
        :param filter_shape: (number of filters, num input feature maps,
                              filter height,filter width)
        :type image_shape: tuple or list of length 4
        :param image_shape: (batch size, num input feature maps,
                             image height, image width)
        :type poolsize: tuple or list of length 2
        :param poolsize: the downsampling (pooling) factor (#rows,#cols)
        """

        assert image_shape[1] == filter_shape[1]
        self.input = input

        # there are "num input feature maps * filter height * filter width"
        # inputs to each hidden unit
        fan_in = numpy.prod(filter_shape[1:])
        # each unit in the lower layer receives a gradient from:
        # "num output feature maps * filter height * filter width" /
        #   pooling size
        fan_out = (filter_shape[0] * numpy.prod(filter_shape[2:]) /
                   numpy.prod(poolsize))
        # initialize weights with random weights
        W_bound = numpy.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
        self.W = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(
            rng.uniform(low=-W_bound, high=W_bound, size=filter_shape),
            dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                               borrow=True)

        # the bias is a 1D tensor -- one bias per output feature map
        b_values = numpy.zeros((filter_shape[0],), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.b = theano.shared(value=b_values, borrow=True)

        # convolve input feature maps with filters
        conv_out = conv.conv2d(input=input, filters=self.W,
                filter_shape=filter_shape, image_shape=image_shape)

        # downsample each feature map individually, using maxpooling
        pooled_out = downsample.max_pool_2d(input=conv_out,
                                            ds=poolsize, ignore_border=True)

        # add the bias term. Since the bias is a vector (1D array), we first
        # reshape it to a tensor of shape (1,n_filters,1,1). Each bias will
        # thus be broadcasted across mini-batches and feature map
        # width & height
        self.output = T.tanh(pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))

        # store parameters of this layer
        self.params = [self.W, self.b]


def evaluate_lenet5(learning_rate=0.1, n_epochs=200,
                    dataset='mnist.pkl.gz',
                    nkerns=[20, 50], batch_size=500):
    """ Demonstrates lenet on MNIST dataset
    :type learning_rate: float
    :param learning_rate: learning rate used (factor for the stochastic
                          gradient)
    :type n_epochs: int
    :param n_epochs: maximal number of epochs to run the optimizer
    :type dataset: string
    :param dataset: path to the dataset used for training /testing (MNIST here)
    :type nkerns: list of ints
    :param nkerns: number of kernels on each layer
    """

    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(23455)

    datasets = load_data(dataset)

    train_set_x, train_set_y = datasets[0]
    valid_set_x, valid_set_y = datasets[1]
    test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]

    # compute number of minibatches for training, validation and testing
    n_train_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
    n_valid_batches = valid_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
    n_test_batches = test_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
    n_train_batches /= batch_size
    n_valid_batches /= batch_size
    n_test_batches /= batch_size

    # allocate symbolic variables for the data
    index = T.lscalar()  # index to a [mini]batch
    x = T.matrix('x')   # the data is presented as rasterized images
    y = T.ivector('y')  # the labels are presented as 1D vector of
                        # [int] labels

    ishape = (28, 28)  # this is the size of MNIST images

    ######################
    # BUILD ACTUAL MODEL #
    ######################
    print '... building the model'

    # Reshape matrix of rasterized images of shape (batch_size,28*28)
    # to a 4D tensor, compatible with our LeNetConvPoolLayer
    layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, 28, 28))

    # Construct the first convolutional pooling layer:
    # filtering reduces the image size to (28-5+1,28-5+1)=(24,24)
    # maxpooling reduces this further to (24/2,24/2) = (12,12)
    # 4D output tensor is thus of shape (batch_size,nkerns[0],12,12)
    layer0 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(rng, input=layer0_input,
            image_shape=(batch_size, 1, 28, 28),
            filter_shape=(nkerns[0], 1, 5, 5), poolsize=(2, 2))

    # Construct the second convolutional pooling layer
    # filtering reduces the image size to (12-5+1,12-5+1)=(8,8)
    # maxpooling reduces this further to (8/2,8/2) = (4,4)
    # 4D output tensor is thus of shape (nkerns[0],nkerns[1],4,4)
    layer1 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(rng, input=layer0.output,
            image_shape=(batch_size, nkerns[0], 12, 12),
            filter_shape=(nkerns[1], nkerns[0], 5, 5), poolsize=(2, 2))

    # the HiddenLayer being fully-connected, it operates on 2D matrices of
    # shape (batch_size,num_pixels) (i.e matrix of rasterized images).
    # This will generate a matrix of shape (20,32*4*4) = (20,512)
    layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)

    # construct a fully-connected sigmoidal layer
    layer2 = HiddenLayer(rng, input=layer2_input, n_in=nkerns[1] * 4 * 4,
                         n_out=500, activation=T.tanh)

    # classify the values of the fully-connected sigmoidal layer
    layer3 = LogisticRegression(input=layer2.output, n_in=500, n_out=10)

    # the cost we minimize during training is the NLL of the model
    cost = layer3.negative_log_likelihood(y)

    # create a function to compute the mistakes that are made by the model
    test_model = theano.function([index], layer3.errors(y),
             givens={
                x: test_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
                y: test_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})

    validate_model = theano.function([index], layer3.errors(y),
            givens={
                x: valid_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
                y: valid_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})

    # create a list of all model parameters to be fit by gradient descent
    params = layer3.params + layer2.params + layer1.params + layer0.params

    # create a list of gradients for all model parameters
    grads = T.grad(cost, params)

    # train_model is a function that updates the model parameters by
    # SGD Since this model has many parameters, it would be tedious to
    # manually create an update rule for each model parameter. We thus
    # create the updates list by automatically looping over all
    # (params[i],grads[i]) pairs.
    updates = []
    for param_i, grad_i in zip(params, grads):
        updates.append((param_i, param_i - learning_rate * grad_i))

    train_model = theano.function([index], cost, updates=updates,
          givens={
            x: train_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
            y: train_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})

    ###############
    # TRAIN MODEL #
    ###############
    print '... training'
    # early-stopping parameters
    patience = 10000  # look as this many examples regardless
    patience_increase = 2  # wait this much longer when a new best is
                           # found
    improvement_threshold = 0.995  # a relative improvement of this much is
                                   # considered significant
    validation_frequency = min(n_train_batches, patience / 2)
                                  # go through this many
                                  # minibatche before checking the network
                                  # on the validation set; in this case we
                                  # check every epoch

    best_params = None
    best_validation_loss = numpy.inf
    best_iter = 0
    test_score = 0.
    start_time = time.clock()

    epoch = 0
    done_looping = False

    while (epoch < n_epochs) and (not done_looping):
        epoch = epoch + 1
        for minibatch_index in xrange(n_train_batches):

            iter = (epoch - 1) * n_train_batches + minibatch_index

            if iter % 100 == 0:
                print 'training @ iter = ', iter
            cost_ij = train_model(minibatch_index)

            if (iter + 1) % validation_frequency == 0:

                # compute zero-one loss on validation set
                validation_losses = [validate_model(i) for i
                                     in xrange(n_valid_batches)]
                this_validation_loss = numpy.mean(validation_losses)
                print('epoch %i, minibatch %i/%i, validation error %f %%' % \
                      (epoch, minibatch_index + 1, n_train_batches, \
                       this_validation_loss * 100.))

                # if we got the best validation score until now
                if this_validation_loss < best_validation_loss:

                    #improve patience if loss improvement is good enough
                    if this_validation_loss < best_validation_loss *  \
                       improvement_threshold:
                        patience = max(patience, iter * patience_increase)

                    # save best validation score and iteration number
                    best_validation_loss = this_validation_loss
                    best_iter = iter

                    # test it on the test set
                    test_losses = [test_model(i) for i in xrange(n_test_batches)]
                    test_score = numpy.mean(test_losses)
                    print(('     epoch %i, minibatch %i/%i, test error of best '
                           'model %f %%') %
                          (epoch, minibatch_index + 1, n_train_batches,
                           test_score * 100.))

            if patience <= iter:
                done_looping = True
                break

    end_time = time.clock()
    print('Optimization complete.')
    print('Best validation score of %f %% obtained at iteration %i,'\
          'with test performance %f %%' %
          (best_validation_loss * 100., best_iter + 1, test_score * 100.))
    print >> sys.stderr, ('The code for file ' +
                          os.path.split(__file__)[1] +
                          ' ran for %.2fm' % ((end_time - start_time) / 60.))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    evaluate_lenet5()


def experiment(state, channel):
    evaluate_lenet5(state.learning_rate, dataset=state.dataset)
```

Comment: have you tried pickling it? and I'm not sure your code adds anything to your question in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to find everywhere that a shared variable is created (`theano.shared`), and pickle the values. If you've got a shared variable `a`, you can use `a.get_value` to get the value of the variable, then pickle this (or use `numpy.save` or `numpy.savez`). When you want to load the network, just load those shared variable values, and assign them to the shared variable again using `a.set_value`.

In your case, an object-oriented way to do things would be to write a `save` and `load` method for your `LeNetConvPoolLayer`. For example, the `save` method could do

```
def save(self, filename):
    np.savez(filename, W=self.W.get_value(), b=self.b.get_value())
```

Then you can use these `save` and `load` functions to save and load each layer as you wish.

Trying to pickle the whole thing is another option, but certain Theano objects won't work properly when they're pickled and loaded (I'm not quite sure which, though, and it might depend for example if your shared variable is stored on the CPU or GPU internally). So best to pickle the values separately as I've described above, especially if you want to store them over a long time or share them between machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in evaluate_lenet5 block, save your model after training finish
open('layer0_model.pkl', 'wb') as f0:
pickle.dump(layer0,f0)
open('layer1_model.pkl', 'wb') as f1:
pickle.dump(layer1,f1)
open('layer2_model.pkl', 'wb') as f2:
pickle.dump(layer0,f2)
open('layer3_model.pkl', 'wb') as f3:
pickle.dump(layer0,f3)



# load the saved model
layer0 = pickle.load(open('layer0_model.pkl'))
layer1 = pickle.load(open('layer1_model.pkl'))    
layer2 = pickle.load(open('layer2_model.pkl'))    
layer3 = pickle.load(open('layer3_model.pkl'))
```